# 3rd layer dilemma

Tags: rubiks-cube

i've followed the beginner's method, i've got the superior facet correct, the 1st and the 2nd layer correct. But in the third layer i always invert the colors but only got one corner right as shown in the pictures. Is there a solution ? 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Weird color scheme!  Normally white is opposite yellow, blue opposite green and orange opposite red.  At least for most of the cubes I've seen.

Answer (score 2):

There is a solution (I got my cube to your position and solved it). Hold the cube with the 3rd layer on top and follow these directions:

1. With the corner that is correct on the right hand side closest to you, use **U R U' L' U R' U' L** until the other corners are in the right spot. This algorithm rotates the front left, back left, and back right corners. It also changes their orientation, which might result in solving the cube (although I don't think it does for your specific case).
2. Now that all the corners are in the proper place, rotate the top layer so that one of the corners that needs to be oriented is in the front right position. Use **2(R' D' R D)** until the corner you were dealing with is oriented properly. Now rotate **ONLY THE TOP LAYER** so that another unoriented corner is in that position. Use the same algorithm until that corner is oriented. Two keys in this step are making sure that you are doing the proper **D** and **D'** (look at the bottom of the cube and figure out which way is clockwise/counter-clockwise) and only rotating the top layer when switching between corners that you are orienting.
3. The top layer is probably 90 or 180 degrees off, so just rotate that back the way it should be.